# C# OpenXML - Table Properties - Set Indent from Left

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a word document with a table on the first page.  It is the first table on the document and only one of the first page.  I need to set the "Indent from left" to 0" on this table.  I'm already appending some text to the document:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument oDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_ms, true))
{
    //Set paragraph, run, and runproperties objects. 
    Paragraph para = oDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>().First();
    Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
    RunProperties runPro = new RunProperties();
    Run lineBreak = new Run(new Break());

    //Set the text color and text value
    Color color = new Color() { Val = "FFFFFF" };
    Text text1 = new Text();
    text1.Text = "text";

    //Add the text to the body
    runPro.Append(color);
    run.Append(runPro);
    run.Append(text1, lineBreak);

    //Close the handle
    oDocument.Close();
}
```

I've read a bit about the TableIndentation class, but haven't found any examples of it being used.  Does anybody have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (note that there are multiple downloads on this page) to inspect a document that has what you need? If not, do so. It will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the table indentation in the table properties class like this.

```
TableProperties tPr = new TableProperties();
tPr.TableIndentation = new TableIndentation() { Type = indentationType, Width = indentationWidth };
```

Comment: Please provide the values for Type and Width as opposed to your app's variable names.

Answer (score 0):

use this and provide width in `DXA(1"=1440 something)`

```
props.TableIndentation = new TableIndentation() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width=-997 };
```

Comment: Under 
**TableWidth class MSDN Library**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablewidth.aspx
1440 twentieths of a point (one inch)
because 1440 twentieths of a point / 20 = 72 and 72 point = 1 inch